# Change SOAP body for python suds call

Tags: python, soap, suds

We have a project that is using suds for some SOAP calls that has been working pretty well until today when I discovered suds is not parsing out the 'choice' objects from the imported wsdl.  With this information, I've been trying to figure out a way to inject the xml required to make the call successful

I'm calling the suds client like so

```
self.client.service.retrieveService()
```

to which suds is making this style call

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
      <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <tns:wsHeader>
          <wss>
            <userName>xxx</userName>
            <password>xxx</password>
          </wss>
          <messageType/>
       </tns:wsHeader>
     </SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <ns1:Body>
       <ns0:retrieveServiceRequest/>
     </ns1:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I've used the suds factory and the wsdl to create the proper input, but I can't figure out how to pass something like this to the client to use for the body:

```
   (retrieveServiceRequest){
     serialNumberWrapper =
      (serialNumberWrapper){
         serialNumber = "1234567890"
      }
   }
```

Note: I've also tried creating my own xml and using __inject, but suds didn't appear to do anything or give any feedback (self.client.last_sent() returns None).  I can provide the only parameter properly pulled from the wsdl for retrieveService to the client call and it will be added to the suds call.

Any advice at this point would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I continued to work at this since it was blocking some bug fixes.  Replace suds with suds_jurko which is just a fork that is still being maintained.